# Why my dweller omit work after dying?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I noticed this now a few times and it slowly begins to be anoying.

My way of handling deathclaw attacks went to be just let them go through room by room untill they are dead, since rearranging the infrastructure of sending my strongest dwellers with them is... fiddly.

But as the title says:

Sometimes after revieving the victims of an Deathclaw attack they appear to lay down work on random occassion and just go into coffe break. Since I noticed this I'm observing this behavior and wasn't able to catch them doing so. But it appears to happen in direct connection with the event of dying. But the change in working state appears to happen while the app itself is closed (can't confirm this so far.)

This is actually anoying since they appear to start working again but on i.e. the next day I have to find them again and reassign them to their jobs. but if there are some times 5 dwellers just idling arround its hard to figure out what the job was for each of them.

Is this issue known?
Is it even an issue or just the result of a feature I'm not aware of/missunderstanding?

Or is it just because Dwellers demand some special leave after dying?

Answer (score -1):

When a dweller dies in fallout shelter and is revived they automatically assigned to "coffee break" (which means they don't have anything assigned to them so they just walk around the vault.)  If a emergency is happening then the dweller will go back to helping out with the emergency.  If there is a fire, the dweller will go back to tending the fire then will go on a coffee break after.